# DRBDManage with Pacemaker on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, failovercluster, pacemaker, drbd

I have 2 `CentOS 7.6` nodes which I have configured with `drbd`, `drbdmanage` and `pacemaker` for active/passive failover.

during a failure my vip and `drbd` service failover from primary to secondary the next node but I couldn't connect to `drbdmanage` to inspect/manage the cluster.

Since `pacemaker` has resource type for drbdmanage I assumed that I should be able to manage and failover the service to the surviving node.

I would like to know whether it's possible to failover `drbdmanage` after a node failure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DRBDmanage will not work correctly in “pure” 2-node setup, because of lost quorum.
drbdmanage will work properly in following cases:

- 1 node
- 2 nodes and both are online. Otherwise the quorum will not exist.
- 2 nodes + witness node https://docs.linbit.com/docs/users-guide-9.0/#s-configuring-quorum-tiebreaker
- 2+ nodes and with node majority

If you need “pure” 2 node high available storage take a look at solutions, which have been designed for it (like [Starwind vsan free](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san#VSAN-FREE))

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I will look at the option with configuring it with witness node as a tiebreaker.

Comment: Just a side note, DRBDManage is deprecated by LINBIT and should no longer be used. Check out LINSTOR if you need to dynamically provision DRBD devices.